# Convert Exception string to Exception class

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

For example, convert the string `'ZeroDivisionError'` to the Python class `ZeroDivisionError`.

One obvious way of doing it is by using an if-else structure, but it is not feasible to do it for all the exceptions present in Python 3.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? If you need the exception object, do not catch it, or rethrow it after cathing.

Comment: I need to extract the underlying Python exception thrown by a wrapped Exception class.